# How to get file name and compare in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the below code to get file name using FILE created event.

```
WriteSilentLog("File Created: " & e.FullPath & " " & Now().ToString)
Dim sFileName As String
Dim FileExt As String

TestPath = e.FullPath '"\\server\E\Accpac Imports\production\reports\1234_maoingfhgh_90676904.pdf"
sFileName = Path.GetFileName(TestPath)
Filename.Text = sFileName
```

It works fine. At the moment the all the file names are end with 'XXXXXXXX' eight digit. I am about to get another file name end with 'XXXXXXXX' random digit of 8  .

My question is How do I differentiate the filename like below

```
' Pseudocode
IF filename Like last 8 digits that have changed in every file Then
    open that pdf file that contain 8 random digits in last
Else If    
    Do somthing
End IF
```

Please Help

Comment: you can suggest me another code that help me out ....

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, do you mean if the text part of the filename is the same with the only difference being the random 8 digits? As in, `daily_report_8987879.pdf` and `daily_report_53526564.pdf` being two similar filenames whereas either of those and `weekly_statement_12347738.pdf` being a file name that isn't like the others. Please clarify and it will be easier to answer the question.

Comment: whole file name is different but i can match the last 8 digits with my emp_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find a file with a known 8 digits at the end;

```
Dim known as integer = 12345678
Dim files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\temp\", "*_" & known & " .pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

'Do something with the files array
```